# Google Web Toolkit on a standalone server

Tags: gwt

Our team is planning on making a thick client into a web based UI. We are researching the various options and GWT is something that we are researching. I have a question if GWT can be deployed by itself (meaning, does it have a built-in web server that can be deployed as a solution?) Appreciate thoughts about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is completely client-side and does not need to communicate with a server (for data purposes), then you can use any web server.  GWT compiles to static JavaScript files, so you can use apache or any other web server to serve up the static files.

If there is a server-side component to your application then you'll need a servlet container.

Answer (score 0):

No built-in web server really except for the development platform which include one... but it's not meant for production.